# Can you have a trigger run depending on the source of Insert, Update or Delete?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Can you have a trigger run depending on the source of Insert, Update or Delete?

**UPD**

Maybe I wasn't too clear in the question above. I want the trigger to run only if the insert came from particular table. For example I have two tables that inserts into TABLE MAIN. I only want the trigger to run if the insert came from Table A. If it came from Table B do not run.

I guess I can use a join to table A? Never used a Trigger in this manner before.

Comment: You can have an `ON INSERT`, an `ON DELETE` and an `ON UPDATE` trigger on every table in your database. So yes, you can have triggers for each of the triggering events.. or you can combine a trigger to be fired on two or even all three of those events..... Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding your question but a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) is a procedure that executes when an event happens in a database.  This event happens on the table you have assigned the trigger to.

Using a sample from [this article](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx), let's say you have tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
 CustomerId smallint identity(1,1),
 Name nvarchar(255),
 Priority tinyint
)

CREATE TABLE Sales (
 TransactionId smallint identity(1,1),
 CustomerId smallint,
 [Net Amount] int,
 Completed bit
)
```

You can create a trigger similar to this which will execute `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Update_Customer_Priority
 ON dbo.Sales
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

WITH CTE AS (
 select CustomerId from inserted
 union
 select CustomerId from deleted
)
UPDATE Customers
SET
 Priority =
  case
   when t.Total < 10000 then 3
   when t.Total between 10000 and 50000 then 2
   when t.Total > 50000 then 1
   when t.Total IS NULL then NULL
  end
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN (
 select
  Sales.CustomerId,
  SUM([Net Amount]) Total
 from Sales
 inner join CTE on CTE.CustomerId = Sales.CustomerId
 where
  Completed = 1
 group by Sales.CustomerId
) t ON t.CustomerId = c.CustomerId

GO
```